# Angular v8 to v11 - entryComponents issue with Ivy disabled

Tags: angular, angular-components, ivy

I've run into an issue with my project's entryComponents once I migrated from v8 to v11.

For the moment I need to disable the Ivy build because I need to stick with the PrimeNG v8 components, and assumed if running 11 with the old build engine the entryComponents array would still be required.  But whenever I trigger a dialog that has an entryComponent embedded I get:

```
Error: No component factory found for DynamicDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

This component in the error is not one of my entryComponents, but a PrimeNG one I use for the dialogs.  If I turn Ivy on, the application is fine - but only in dev mode.  If built for prod it moans about the Prime modules being out of date, so I need it off until I have time to refactor.

Is there a way to define these entryComponents in v11 with Ivy off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is resolved and I'm ashamed to say it was a silly one! Somehow (probably during the initial Prime migration to 11) the DynamicDialogModule had been removed from all modules:

```
import { DynamicDialogModule } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';
```

Added it back everywhere and the problem's gone. I'll get my coat.... :(